# Show a QT UI in another one

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have a project including 3 UI files: `win_main.ui`, `win_table.ui` and `win_table2.ui`.

I want to show one of them inside of `win_main.ui`, and with a button, change them.
I mean, there is a Box containing `win_table.ui`, and when I clicked the button, the box will change to `win_table2.ui`.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O41Yc.png)

I tried using QWidget, QQuickWidget, but they didn't worked.

Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Please insert the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question! Without code, it's hard to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html). You can flip between tables using tabs.

[image: QTabWidget layout]

If there is a specific reason why you wouldn't want `win_table2.ui` showing before a button is pressed, you can disable that tab programmatically until it is ready. You can also flip between which tab is currently showing using code as well.

Comment: actually my point is i want to design the box in another UI file, if i use QTabWidget, i should design the table in the win_main.ui (at least i think so!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still can. Try creating `win_main.ui` as a QMainWindow and `win_table.ui` /  `win_table2.ui` as QWidgets. Then in the QTabWidget, make each tab a QWidget container. Then you can add `win_table.ui` and `win_table2.ui` to the respective tabs.